# There are no PK in the referenced table. Why?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL to create 3 SQL tables:

```
create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Posts_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Active bit not null 
    constraint DF_Posts_Active default (0)
);

create table dbo.PostsLocalized
(
  Id int not null, 
  Culture int not null
    constraint CK_PostsLocalized_Culture check ([Culture] in ('1', '2', '3')),
  [Text] nvarchar (200) not null,
    constraint PK_PostsLocalized_Id_Culture primary key clustered (Id, Culture)
);

create table dbo.Tags
(
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Tags_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar not null 
);

create table dbo.PostsLocalized_Tags
(
  PostLocalizedId int not null, 
  TagId int not null,
    constraint PK_PostsLocalized_Tags_Post_PostLocalizedId_TagId primary key clustered (PostLocalizedId, TagId)
);
```

Then I have added the following constraints:

```
alter table dbo.PostsLocalized
add constraint FK_PostsLocalized_Id foreign key (Id) references dbo.Posts(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;

alter table dbo.PostsLocalized_Tags
add constraint FK_PostsLocalized_Tags_PostLocalizedId foreign key (PostLocalizedId) references PostsLocalized(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint FK_PostsLocalized_Tags_TagId foreign key (TagId) references Tags(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

But I get the following error:

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'PostsLocalized' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_PostsLocalized_Tags_PostLocalizedId'.
```

How can I solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server mandates that foreign key references be to a primary key or unique key.  The foreign key reference has to be to *all* the columns that constitute the primary/unique key.  The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) says:

> In a foreign key reference, a link is created between two tables when
>   the column or columns that hold the primary key value for one table
>   are referenced by the column or columns in another table. This column
>   becomes a foreign key in the second table.
>
> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table. A FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint can contain null values; however, if any column of a
>   composite FOREIGN KEY constraint contains null values, verification of
>   all values that make up the FOREIGN KEY constraint is skipped. To make
>   sure that all values of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint are
>   verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating columns.

The primary key in `PostsLocalized` contains the `culture` column, so you need to add it into the foreign key reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your PK on `PostsLocalized` table is complex consisting of two columns - `id` and `culture` and you are trying to create FK on only one of those columns which is not possible.

You'll have to either add `Culture` column on `PostsLocalized_Tags` and use them both in foreign key or remove `Culture` from your PK on `PostLocalized`